# Progress Wizard in Oracle Apex 19: How to set progression of pages?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I am modelling an online store application on Oracle Apex where people can create an order. For this purpose I want to create a progress wizard, so that data can be shown from multiple tables and entered into multiple tables too. 
Oracle has a really good Sample DataBase Application which implements this progress wizard really efficiently. [This is the first page of the progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keTOc.png)

I have copied all 4 relevant pages into my application, and have modified the PL/SQL code according to my own tables. I also copied the list from shared components that is used in this progress bar and modified that with respect to my own pages. 
Now when I try to create an order(meaning open the first page or step of the wizard), I land on the first page. I enter the values and then as soon as I press next, an error appears saying that the application cannot identify page 12.
The thing is that in the sample database application, the next button really is suppose to redirect you to page 12.

However, in my application, I expected it to land on page 22 (which is the next page in my list and the next in the sequence). 
To try to modify this, I went to my wizard's first page, and tried to edit my click button so that it is redirected to my next page. However, the problem is that the button has only an option to submit. We cannot tell it where to go after submission. 
[as you can see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxfz4.png)

So If anyone can guide me on how to solve this, I'd be really grateful. I have tried googling it a gazillion time but haven't found any answer.

EDIT: It appears to me that there was some sort of glitch in PL/SQL code. Thus, I have given up this course of action

Comment: Try setting a Branch for after submit. Or you can change the Action on the button to Redirect to page in this application

Comment: Not sure what your level of apex experience is but it might be a lot easier if you let Apex create the wizard pages for you. In the Create Page menu, you can select "wizard". That will give you a form where you can set the number of pages you need. The navigation between the pages is then generated automatically